# VBA error 462 "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" after sending email via Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, remote-server

I've written a VBA code that goes through the emails in Inbox and forwards them if specified conditions are met. For me it's working correctly. Unfortunately one user is getting error 462 after forwarding the first email (if the conditions are not met it goes through the loop and checks next items, error appears after forwarding the first possible email).

```
    Sub ForwardEmails(Optional bSend As Boolean = True)
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim objNS As Object
    Dim sFolder As Object
    Dim sInbox As String, sName As String
    Dim Item As Object, ForwardItem As Object
    Dim i As Integer, iDateDiff As Integer
    Dim dDate As Date, dItemTime As Date
    Dim bForward As Boolean
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim myMails

    sInbox = "Inbox"

    ''''''''go to indicated Outlook account and subfolders
    On Error GoTo NoAccount
        Set sFolder = objNS.Folders(sAccount).Folders(sInbox)
    On Error GoTo 0

    dStartTime = Now
    Set myMails = sFolder.Items

    '''''''go through all items in inbox
    i = 4
    myMails.Sort "ReceivedTime", False

    For Each Item In myMails
        dItemTime = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            dItemTime = Item.receivedtime
            If dItemTime = 0 Then
                dItemTime = Item.creationtime
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        If dItemTime > 0 Then 'message type email, report etc, something that contains received time or creation time
            If dItemTime >= dStartDate Then

                If dItemTime <= dStartTime Then

                   If Len(Item.Categories) = 0 Then 'if email is not not categorized then proceed
                    bForward = True
                        If Len(sNotForward) > 0 Then 'if there is a restriction (text for not forwarded emails) then check
                            If Item.body Like "*" & sNotForward & "*" Then
                                bForward = False
                            End If
                        End If
                        If Len(sNotForward2) > 0 Then 'if there is a restriction (text for not forwarded emails) then check
                            If Item.body Like "*" & sNotForward2 & "*" Then
                                bForward = False
                            End If
                        End If
                        If bForward Then
                            Item.Categories = sCategory
                            Item.Save
                            Set ForwardItem = Nothing
                            On Error Resume Next
                                Set ForwardItem = Item.Forward
                            On Error GoTo 0
                            If ForwardItem Is Nothing Then 'if the type is different than olMail or similar and item can't be forwarded - create new item and attach the original item
                                Set ForwardItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                                ForwardItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = sSender
                                ForwardItem.attachments.Add Item
                                ForwardItem.Subject = "FW: " & Replace(Item.Subject, "Undeliverable: ", "")
                                ForwardItem.display
                                Call RemoveSignature
                            End If
                            ForwardItem.Recipients.Add sRecipient
                            ForwardItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = sSender
                            ForwardItem.display

                            **If bSend Then
                                'ForwardItem.send
                                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
                                Application.SendKeys "%s"
                                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
                            End If**


                            i = i + 1
                        End If
                   End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    **Next Item**
    Set myMails = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Completed. Forwarded " & i - 4 & " messages."
    Exit Sub

NoAccount:
    MsgBox "No such account or folder."
End Sub
```

The error appears in the line "Next Item" (bold). Without the bold part of the code that sends email using shortcut (the message is only displayed), it works without error.
I tried late binding and early binding with the same result. It looks like after sending one email it 'losts' reference to outlook app? Do you have any suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get an `Explorer` instance and keep it alive if you want to keep Outlook running until you are done.

Also, I have noticed the following code:

```
For Each Item In myMails
```

Iterating over all items in the folder is a time-consuming task and definetely not recommended way to go. Instead, you may consider using the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods instead. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)